# loopback remote method to read contents of uploaded file

Tags: node.js, file-upload, loopback

I am trying to read the contents of the file uploaded to a remote method created in loopback. The API will be called using postman and will attach a file with the request. I have added the following method with no luck so far:

```
module.exports = function(Upload) {

Upload.testUpload = function(file, cb) {

    fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        //console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
        cb(null, data.toString(), 'application/octet-stream');
    });    
  }

  Upload.remoteMethod(
    'testUpload', {
        isStatic: true,
        returns: [
            {arg: 'body', type: 'file', root: true},
            {arg: 'Content-Type', type: 'string', http: { target: 'header' }}
        ]
    }
  );

}
```

Could anyone please let me know, exact way to upload files in loopback?
Thanks

Comment: first thing to know is that your inventoryFeed accepts a "file" parameter, but you haven't defined it in your remotemethod

Comment: so on using      accepts: [
                { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' } },
                { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } }
            ], the uploaded file will be available in req.file right ?

Comment: i edited your code, so, the below code is working;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to upload files in loopback is to use loopback-component-storage module. Install the module using the following command:

```
npm install loopback-component-storage
```

Create datasource by modifying server/datasources.json file using the code below:

```
  "storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./server/storage"
  }
```

Create "container" model by updating model-config.json file with the following code:

```
  "container": {
    "dataSource": "storage",
    "public": true
  }
```

Then create server/models/container.js and server/models/container.json with the following code:

```
module.exports = function(Container) {

};
```

and

```
{
  "name": "container",
  "base": "Model",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Once all these steps are done, we can start uploading files using Postman.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution without using **loopback-component-storage** (it can be useful if you don't wanna save uploaded file or if you want to attach file uploading logic directly to your *model.js* file).

1) Install [**`express-fileupload`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) package:

`npm i express-fileupload --save`

2) Add **express-fileupload** to your *server.js* file:

```
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
app.use(fileUpload())
```

3) Update your model file, like this:

```
module.exports = function(Job) {
  Job.uploadFile = (req, res, cb) => {
    console.log(req.files)
    cb(null, null)
  }

  Job.remoteMethod('uploadFile', {
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
      {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}},
    ],
    http: {
      path: '/upload-file',
      verb: 'post',
      status: 200,
    },
  })
}
```

Now you can access to your uploaded files with **req.files** property.

Comment: This does not work. In my remote method function req.files is undefined. I've tried moving the `app.use(fileUpload()` call all over the server.js file and it does not respect the .xlxs file I am sending via postman